# angularjs directive watch not fired on object function property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

TL;DR: updating a property on a watched object does not seem to fire the watch when the property is a  **function** .

## Live example

See [this Plnkr exampl](http://plnkr.co/edit/pFhgfQLvD0hobxAgYOk6?p=info).

The `config` object's properties can be changed by clicking the buttons in the example. The objects are in sync (between directive and controller), and the `$watch` function in the directive (which simply ups a counter in this case) is called when a property is changed. *Except* when a function property is changed, which is what I do not understand.

## Dead example

### View

```
<main-dir config="configObject"></main-dir>
```

### Directive

```
myApp.directive('mainDir', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {config: '='},
        link: function (scope, el) {

            //(initialisation code)
                           
            scope.$watch("config", function (config) {
                if (!config) return;
                // do stuff with config object
            }, true);

         }
     };
 });
```

### Controller

```
//init:
$scope.configObject = {
    propA: "value",
    propB: [1,2,3],
    propC: {key0: 3, key1: "value"},
    propD: function(x) {return x+1;}
}

//elsewhere:
$scope.configObject.propA = "other value"; //fires watch in directive
//or
$scope.configObject.propB = [3,2,1]; //fires watch in directive
//or
$scope.configObject.propB.push(5); //fires watch in directive
//or
$scope.configObject.propC = {key0: 1, key2: 34}; //fires watch in directive
//or
$scope.configObject.propC["key100"] = "newValue"; //fires watch in directive
//
// ... BUT ...
//
$scope.configObject.propD = function (x) {return x+2;} //does NOT fire watch in directive
```

So, in short: I can get the `$watch` to fire on changes to the object's properties. But that doesn't seem to work if the property is a function.

Workaround:
When changing a property that is a function, I add a line changing a non-function property to fire the watch, like so:

```
$scope.configObject.propD = function (x) {/*...new function def...*/};
$scope.configObject.xxx = Math.random(); //<-- causes watch to fire
```

Does anyone know why that is the case? Can I get the `$watch` to fire also on changes to *function* properties of the config object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope.$watch("config.propD") will watch reference to function instead of returning value
scope.$watch("config.xxx") will watch return value from Math.random because you called function

Simplest way is to use $watchCollection [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) but it's not perfect one

```
  scope.$watchCollection('config',
    function(config) {
      scope.caught++;
    }
  );
```

Another way is to program collection of $watch'ers it's work slightly better:

```
  angular.forEach(scope.config, function(value, key) {
    scope.$watch(function() {
      return scope.config[key];
    }, function(config) {
      scope.caught2++;
    }, true);
  });
```

Comment: But I want to pass a function as propC - not its return value. The function is then used in the directive's link. Of course, it's more useful then returning 8.

Comment: But you want to $watch return value of function? So the ex I provided should work even if you pass function to directive

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if I follow. `config` is an object, with various properties that I want to use in the directive. The directive should notice a change in the properties' values, even if a property is a function definition. (Imagine changing `config.propC = function(x){return x^2;}` to `config.propC = function(x){return x^3;}`. I _could_ put a dedicated watch on `config.propC`, but I use a `config` object because it groups all related information needed to handle a change in either one of its properties. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I could, I suppose, turn the `config` object (`config = {propA: "val", propB: [1,2,3], propC: function(x){return x^2;}`) into a `config` _function returning that object_ (`config = function(){return {propA: "val", propB: [1,2,3], propC: function(x){return x^2;};}`) and then `$watch` not `config` but `config()`, but it seems unnecessarily complex. Moreover, I could then no longer individually change the property values of the object, defeating its purpose.

Comment: I thought we are talking only about function watcher.
I exited answer, it isn't beautiful but it will work

Comment: Hey Artur, thank you for your update. I've added a Plunker example to further clarify my issue (and changed the original question to reflect it) further, please have a look if you want.
The problem with your edited approach is that the second `$watch` must do the exact same thing as the first. I could add a function that is called by both, but this is very unelegant and I cannot imagine there is not a better solution...

Comment: The new answer is working well with your Plumker but I would recommend usage of $watchCollection (comes in angular 1.1.4)

Comment: I tried updating my Plunker to 1.1.4 and using `$watchCollection`. This indeed solves the problem for `propD` (so assigning a different function does fire the watcher now), but another problem appears, which is that _adding_ to `propB` and `propC` no longer works :/ Forked Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8jzrVBRRJ1VYzuMz0vDk) Any suggestions?

Comment: It's more verbose than I'd expect it'd need to be, but it works -- thanks!